# How we use services with rules

Tags: web-services, service, drupal-7, drupal-rules

I want to use drupal rules with services module.
I have with services_rule module. It's not working for me. I did't find event for service.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: show us what you have so far.

Comment: i'm just create a webservice with POST / GET parameter.
make a condition using these args create a node from rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have done it.

Step to use services_rule module with services module in drupal 7.

Step 1: You have to create component in rules. Now you see there is permission option available for this.

[image]

You can define variables as argument used in web service . Please see screenshot.

Step 2: 
Enable this source from service resources: admin/structure/services

See screenshot

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Right now drupal does not have that capability. To show you this, I am including a link to the drupal website where many others had the same question.

https://groups.drupal.org/node/10376